# RUBY_ON_RAILS - registrations_controller.rb - não consigo resolver o bug de permissão para registrar usuário!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4

Método `create`:

```
 def create
 # super
 build_resource(sign_up_params)
```

Método de permissão:

```
def sign_up_params

         params.require(:usuario).permit(:nome, 
                                          :email,
                                          :password, 
                                          :password_confirmation,
                                          :possui_planejador,
                                          :profissional_id,
                                          :tipo_profissional,
                                          :nome_escritorio,
                                          :subdominio_escritorio,
                                          :tipo,
                                          :especialidade => [],
                                          perfil_attributes: [
                                            :id,
                                            :avatar,
                                            :origem,
                                            :cpf,
                                            :cidade,
                                            :estado,
                                            :profissao,
                                            :nome,
                                            :telefone,
                                            :data_nascimento,
                                            {:certificacao_ids => []}
                                          ])
end
```

Sempre que uso `rails s` pra subir no servidor, ele da erro no método `permit`. Já tentei inúmeras coisas e não sei o que fazer. A versão do rails é a `5.1.0`, ruby `2.3.0`.

É um sistema de cadastro de usuários, quando cria um usuário, outra tabelas são criadas também, como a do perfil do usuário.

Estou usando a gem `binding.pry` para debugar e o `devise` para authenticação.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Erro que aparece:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `permit!' for #Array:0x0055993ffdb370
> Did you mean?  permutation):
> app/controllers/api/v1/registrations_controller.rb:201:in 'sign_up_params'

Answer (score 2):

Você tentou usar o método `configure_permitted_parameters` que a documentação do devise aponta? https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#strong-parameters

Eu acredito que possa resolver o seu problema. É só colocar no ApplicationController algo assim:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:nome, 
                                      :email,
                                      :password, 
                                      :password_confirmation,
                                      :possui_planejador,
                                      :profissional_id,
                                      :tipo_profissional,
                                      :nome_escritorio,
                                      :subdominio_escritorio,
                                      :tipo,
                                      :especialidade => [],
                                      perfil_attributes: [
                                        :id,
                                        :avatar,
                                        :origem,
                                        :cpf,
                                        :cidade,
                                        :estado,
                                        :profissao,
                                        :nome,
                                        :telefone,
                                        :data_nascimento,
                                        {:certificacao_ids => []}
                                      ]])
  end
end
```

Espero ter ajudado.

EDIT: acredito que você nem precise colocar nesse hash os atributos padrões do devise, como email, password e password_confirmation